# ¿Cómo restaurar un archivo Sql.bak en c# con el nombre original de la base de datos?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Estoy intentando restaurar una base de datos SQL mediante c#, pero necesito que la base de datos recupere su nombre original (este nombre no lo conozco) ¿Existe alguna manera de hacerlo?.

Por ejemplo, si en **SQLManagmentStudio** quiero restaurar el backUp `MyDatabase.bak` mediante el asistente, éste de manera automática obtiene el nombre de la base de datos:
[image: Asistente de restauración de bases de datos]

Esta acción me genera la siguiente query:

```
USE [master] RESTORE DATABASE [myDataBase] FROM  DISK = N'C:\Users\PROG\Respaldo.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5
```

El problema con esta consulta es que es necesario especificar el nombre de la base datos.

Es decir ¿Existe una manera de restaurar el respaldo omitiendo el parámetro de nombre de la base de datos ( ya que este valor es desconocido)? Algo así:

> RESTORE DATABASE FROM  DISK = N'C:\Users\PROG\Respaldo.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5*

Espero puedan ayudarme, 
Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no existe una manera de restaurar una base de datos sin el nombre de la base de datos.

Pero puedes obtener el nombre de la base de datos desde el archivo .bak y luego ejecutar el comando restore database.

el siguiente codigo sql, se encuentra en la pregunta [How can I retrieve the logical file name of the database from backup file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089627/how-can-i-retrieve-the-logical-file-name-of-the-database-from-backup-file)

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (
    LogicalName varchar(128),
    [PhysicalName] varchar(128), 
    [Type] varchar, 
    [FileGroupName] varchar(128), 
    [Size] varchar(128),
    [MaxSize] varchar(128), 
    [FileId]varchar(128), 
    [CreateLSN]varchar(128), 
    [DropLSN]varchar(128), 
    [UniqueId]varchar(128), 
    [ReadOnlyLSN]varchar(128), 
    [ReadWriteLSN]varchar(128),
    [BackupSizeInBytes]varchar(128), 
    [SourceBlockSize]varchar(128), 
    [FileGroupId]varchar(128), 
    [LogGroupGUID]varchar(128), 
    [DifferentialBaseLSN]varchar(128), 
    [DifferentialBaseGUID]varchar(128), 
    [IsReadOnly]varchar(128), 
    [IsPresent]varchar(128), 
    [TDEThumbprint]varchar(128),
    [SnapshotUrl]varchar(128)
)
DECLARE @Path varchar(1000)='C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup\MyDataBase.bak'
DECLARE @LogicalNameData varchar(128),@LogicalNameLog varchar(128)
INSERT INTO @table
EXEC('
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK=''' +@Path+ '''
   ')

   SET @LogicalNameData=(SELECT LogicalName FROM @Table WHERE Type='D')
   SET @LogicalNameLog=(SELECT LogicalName FROM @Table WHERE Type='L')

SELECT @LogicalNameData as databaseName,@LogicalNameLog as databaseLogFile
```

entonces una vez con la variable @LogicalNameData puedes restaurar la base de datos

```
USE [master] RESTORE DATABASE @LogicalNameData FROM  DISK = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup\MyDataBase.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5
```